# ¿Por qué "enturcado" quiere decir enfadado en Nicaragua?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, historia, nicaragua

Leo [en Twitter](https://twitter.com/Monimbro/status/1003779352520286208):

> Sabes que algo mal está pasando en Nicaragua cuando el ave nacional tiene cara de enturcado. #SOSNicaragua
>
> [image]

Y, efectivamente, enturcado indica cólera según el DLE:

> [**enturcado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FqcT4Ua)
>   1. adj. Nicaragua. encolerizado.
>
> > [**encolerizado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=F87d15y)
> >     Del part. de encolerizar.
> >
> > 1. adj. Lleno de cólera (‖ ira).

Y lo mismo con el DAMER:

> [**enturcado, -a.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=enturcado)
>   I.  1.  adj. Nicaragua. Referido a persona, enfadada, encolerizada. pop + cult → espon.

Por tanto, resulta que *enturcado* quiere decir *lleno de cólera*. tuBabel da un ejemplo:

> [**enturcado**](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/763-enturcado)
>
> enojado
>   Se utiliza para decir que uno esta muy pero muy molesto con alguien o por algo.

Lo gracioso del caso es que la palabra *enturcado* nos remite rápidamente a *turco*, propio de Turquía. Sin embargo, Nicaragua y Turquía son países tan lejanos que cuesta ver cuál puede haber sido su relación.

¿Exist alguna teoría sobre cómo *enturcado* acabó convirtiéndose en Nicaragua en sinónimo de *enfadado*?

Comment: En la jerga de Nicaragua, hay una otra palabra con más o menos el mismo significado: [**encachimbado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EwfcgdT). Google Books dice que estes diccionarios tienen entradas de *enturcado*, pero desafortunadamente no hay prevista: [*Diccionario de fraseologismos usados en Nicaragua*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9rwuAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA232&dq=enturcado) (p.232); [*Diccionario de uso del español nicaragüense*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rrwuAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA80&dq=enturcado) (p.80)

Comment: Parece que en Nicaragua "la turca" es el pene.

Comment: @Rodrigo ¡qué gran pista esta! El [DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=turca) lo confirma y también da la acepción _Persona mezquina, tacaña. desp_. Seguro que el tema va por allí, si bien la presunta relación con Turquía sigue siendo una incógnita.

Comment: Sobre lo de "persona tacaña", los inmigrantes árabes y judíos que llegaron a América (o se _los turcos_) ocuparon el nicho del comercio minorista, y son tildados como mezquinos.

Comment: @Rodrigo - De acuerdo, en México hay una pequeña clase mercantil y capitalista poblada de muchos nombres árabes.  Yo pienso que esta podría ser la explicación, sin necesidad de otras conjeturas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Enturcado*** forma parte del grupo de malsonancias latinoamericanas en las que se relaciona la ira con los genitales masculinos y la excitación sexual. Desconozco la exacta razón de esta relación, pero imagino que tiene que ver con la agresividad del macho en la conducta sexual de los mamíferos, y todo aquello.

> **[envergado, -a](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=envergado)**.
>
> I.  1.  adj. Ho. Referido a persona, irritada, enojada.
>
> **[encojonado, -a](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=encojonado)**.
>
> I.  1.  adj. Ho, Cu, RD, Ve:O. Referido a persona, irritada, enojada. vulg; pop + cult → espon.
>
> **[caliente](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=caliente)**.
>
> I.  1.  adj. ES, Pa, Co, Pe, Bo, Ur; Gu, Ch, p.u; Ve, pop + cult → espon; Ec, pop. Referido a persona, muy enfadada.
>
> **[empijado, -a](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=empijado)**.
>
> I.  1.  adj. Ho. Referido a persona, muy enfadada, encolerizada. vulg.
>
> **[pichado, -a](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pichado)**.
>
> I.  1.  adj/sust. Py. Referido a persona, que se enoja con facilidad. pop + cult → espon.
>
> **[empingado, -a](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=empingado)**.
>
> I.  1.  adj. Cu. Referido a persona, enfadada, enojada.

En Nicaragua y al parecer también en Honduras al pene se le dice "turco" o preferiblemente **"la turca"**. Esto porque los turcos, al menos en la versión más estereotípica de su raza, tienen la **nariz grande**. Ojo, que en América les decimos "turcos" no solo a los nativos de Turquía, sino a todos los árabes e incluso a los judíos, quienes son famosos mundialmente por su narizota.

Entonces en este juego el pene es "la narigona". (Por su forma, creo que queda claro, no voy a poner una ilustración.)

"Enturcarse", como las demás palabras de la lista, significaría literalmente algo así como "volverse pene" o, tal vez, "erectársele a uno el pene". Por lo tanto, "excitarse sexualmente", Y luego en sentido figurado, "irritarse".